# How to find second occurence of specified value from user input and return the values in between

Tags: python

Currently trying to write a script that takes a user input that has multiple numbers, a hypen, then a string of letters, another hyphen and some numbers. What I'm trying to do is display the values between the two hyphens.

Here's what I have so far

```
serialNum = input("Input the serial code of the product please")

hyphenIndex = serialNum.find("-")
print("The color of the product is ", serialNum[hyphenIndex:])
```

Comment: can you share some inputs and outputs?

Comment: an input would be "34783-red-348943" and the output would just be red

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you always have the input between hyphens, the most simple thing you can do is splitting on the hyphen and get the second value:

```
serialNum = "34783-red-348943"
print("The color of the product is ",  serialNum.split("-")[1])
```

Comment: Yes that works! I'm new to python so still learning all the different methods and got too tunnel visioned on .find